# Multiple choice dropdown is not shown correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to integrate one code piece with multiple dependent dropdown list into my contact form. In any case it is shown as simple list until I take off 'multiple' tag. Anybody knows where is the problem?

It should work like this: http://demo.webslesson.info/muli-select-dynamic-dependent-dropdown-listbox/.

And this what it looks like now: https://ibb.co/VJ78rkS.

```
                <h5 class="card-title text-center" style="font-size: 26px">Test contact form</h5>
                <form method="post" action="email-script.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="emailForm">
                    <select id="first_level" name="first_level[]" multiple class="form-control">
                     <?php
                     foreach($result as $row)
                     {
                      echo '<option value="'.$row["first_level_category_id"].'">'.$row["first_level_category_name"].'</option>';
                     }
                     ?>
                    </select><br>
                    <select id="second_level" name="second_level[]" multiple class="form-control">

                    </select><br>
                    <select id="third_level" name="third_level[]" multiple class="form-control">
                
                    </select><br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" >
                        <div id="nameError" style="color: red;font-size: 14px;display: none">surnameError</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control"  placeholder="Phone" >
                        <div id="phoneError" style="color: red;font-size: 14px;display: none">subjectError</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" class="form-control">
                        <div id="attachmentError" style="color: red;font-size: 14px;display: none">attachmentError</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submit">
                        <center><input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return validateEmailSendForm();" class="btn btn-success" value="SUBMIT"></center>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Full code:
https://pastebin.com/fxG0U9XH

Comment: The one in your demo looks like it's done with some custom code involving divs and checkboxes, plus javascript, it's not just a standard select

Comment: The accompanying tutorial shows that it relies on a jquery plugin to get that effect

Comment: Yes, there's jquery for parsing dropdown values from database. But now the main thing is frontend.

Comment: There is also jquery for formatting it. Look more closely, it relies on a plugin called "multiselect"